# How to run Excel VBA macro continuously?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to Auto Sort a table in Excel when any value in the table is changed.
This is my VBA code

```
Sub Macro3(ByVal target As Range)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table4[Pts]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table4[GD]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table4[GF]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = True
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Sub sort()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("Table4")
    Call Macro3(target)
End Sub
```

What should I do to let this macro run continuously each time values in the table change?

Comment: Have you thought this through? Won't the user find it confusing if the chart sorts while they are editing it? What will happen to their current cell? They press tab - so the cell changed. That means the list is sorted. What will you do about the selection?

Comment: the cell is  changed due to formulas in other cells, the key point of the table is to get it sorted when cells' values are changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro will not be triggered when cell values are changed due to a cell's formula recalculating from a change in another worksheet. You need to capture the [Worksheet_Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838823.aspx) event for that.

This is not module code. It belongs on Sheet1's code page. Right-click the Sheet1 tab at the bottom of your workbook and choose View Code. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the into the pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    On Error Goto bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ListObjects("Table4").Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("Table4[[#All],[Pts]]"), Order:=xlDescending
            .Add Key:=Range("Table4[[#All],[GD]]"), Order:=xlDescending
            .Add Key:=Range("Table4[[#All],[GF]]"), Order:=xlDescending
        End With
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. If the formulas recalculate, the data in Table4 will be resorted. Events monitoring is temporarily suspended so that the act of sorting does not trigger another calculation event.

Answer (score 0):

To have a macro run every time a cell in a table / range changes, you can use [*events*](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx), which you put in the code for the sheet.

In your case, you probably want something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, range_of_table) Is Nothing Then
    Call sort
  End If
End Sub
```

Where range_of_table is the range of the table you've created.

Comment: what is the syntax of "range_of_table" variable?
The Range I have is a Table Named "Table4"
how can I write It correctly in the function?

Comment: It must be a range-object, e.g. Range("Table4") as used in the Sort() macro you used above (although personally I would qualify what worksheet the range is on as well). Basically what you say is that if the `Target`-range (the range which was changed, which triggered the event) and another range which you qualify either in the function call or earlier in the macro, you execute the code inside the if-statement. Also note that this goes in  the sheet's code-module, not into a regular code-module.

Comment: when I want to run this code, the Subroutine "sort" is the macro which appear in the macro list, not the "worksheet_Change"
so "worksheet_change" subroutine does not change anything in the macro!